# Best Way to create Custom Poll Web part in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-search-web-part, survey-list, custom-web-parts

I need to create a custom poll web part, My requirement is User able to responds the poll, the admin needs to create a poll question, He needs options to choose the poll options type (checkbox, radio button, textbox..).Once Admin Published the Poll, It needs to show to the user. SO I need suggestion for best practices

1. Shall we Use Content Search Web part and Survey list as a back end for Creating the Poll web part?
   If we are going by this method means, Is this possible to get the responses from the survey list?
   or
2. Shall we use Custom web part and custom list like this (http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5755)
   (http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-create-sharepoint-2010-polling.html)

Please give some suggestions for above steps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you decide to use OOTB Survey list, You should take care of two main factors.

1. **Time:**

   - The time required to customize the current OOTB survey list to match your requirements.
   - And the time required to build a custom Survey from scratch.
2. **Flexibility:**

   - To be able to achieve the current and future requirements without a headache.

**Regarding Which option should you use?**

In fact, it mainly depends on the customization required and your development experience.

**The first option** will save the time `(depend on your requirements)` meanwhile it's very poor and not flexible to be customized to meet the current and future requirements.

**The second option** will take a lot of time `(depend on your requirements and your development experience)` but I think it's so flexible and you would avoid the customization complexity to achieve the new requirements.

**In my opinion,** I preferred to use the second option especially if you have a  complex customization. Meanwhile, you don't know what's the size of the new enhancement that should you do in the future?!

I know building your own poll from scratch will take a lot of time at the beginning. but trust and believe me, Customizing the current poll to match your new requirements will take time more than building a new one from scratch.